# Where to enter values for QGIS classification widget type

Tags: qgis, forms

How can I generate a form in QGIS where I have several options for a column as predefined possibilities?

So in my case I want to create a column where the values `local`, `regional` and `global` are allowed. I hence created the column `scale` and then tried to change the widget-type to `classification`.

[image]

I just can't figure out where to provide the drop-down options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to use "Value Map" instead of "Classification" in Widget type.

You may look at the documentation to better understand what each widget type is intended to https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#edit-widgets